# How to connect my Google Assistant app to my own server

Tags: node.js, firebase, parsing, actions-on-google, back4app

I'm creating an actions on google smart home app. I need to use a server that lets me make external (to Google) calls. I've already tried it with Firebase, but it's not possible unless you upgrade your account. What platform could I use to accomplish this task?

I have already searched for alternatives to Firebase, and came up with platforms such us parse, back4app or horizon, but I don't actually know if they are suitable for my purpose. Does anyone know which one could I use and how can I link it with my actions on google app?

Comment: You may consider to use Blaze plan on Firebase. It has same free limit as Spark plan and it will be enough for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways you could go.

1. Upgrade to the pay-as-you-go Blaze plan. You can look at the [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) for the tier and see if it makes sense.
2. As Actions on Google has fulfillment that is at its core a REST API call, you can host the fulfillment directly on your server and respond using one of the libraries or directly through JSON.
3. As the platform is basically a REST API call, you can use any server / cloud function service to generate calls. I don't know anything about the three suggestions you make, but as long as you can run code on them they should work.